# Applescript : text with variable (remove missing variable)

Tags: variables, text, applescript, missing-data

I have a script which is saving a text file :

set myNote to " 
    Text
    Text 
    Text

```
more text: " & variable 1 & "

" & variable 2 & "
" & variable 3 & "
" & variable 4 & "

More text ....
" & Variable 5 & "
```

The "issue" is that variables are sometime blank and so I have a few blank line between the text

Like :

> more text: variable 1
>
> Variable 3
>
> More text .... Variable 5

How can I remove the blank line if the variable have no value ?

Should I set the variable as missing value instead " " or would that do the same ?

Second idea I have is

```
If variable1 is not = to " " then 
Set note1 to variable1
End if
```

set

```
 note1 to 
Text
    Text 
    Text

 Set note2 to    
    more text: " & variable 1 & "

Set note3 to    
    " & variable 2 & "
```

Set note to note1 &note2 and note3

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to make "myNote" into a text of variables and if the variable is just "" then not leave a blank line, you could use something like this:

```
set myNote to "Text Text Text" & return

if variable1 is not "" then
    set myNote to myNote & return & variable1
end if
if variable2 is not "" then
    set myNote to myNote & return & variable2
end if
if variable3 is not "" then
    set myNote to myNote & return & variable3
end if
if variable4 is not "" then
    set myNote to myNote & return & variable4
end if
if variable5 is not "" then
     set myNote to myNote & return & "More Text .... " & variable5
end if
```